# Grok logstash pipeline not filtering texts

Tags: logstash-grok

I am new to Elasticstack. I am trying to implement a logstash pipeline in which the a file would be processed and it would filter and output if the line of file contains following keyword -

1. java.lang.Exception - Any line of file containing Exception should be filtered and be available on Kibana
2. XYZ process completed.

I tried following but it seems to outputting all the contents that do not match the Exception too-

```
    input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    tags => "exception"
  }
}
filter{
  if "exception" in [tags]{
  
  
    grok {
    match => { message => "Exception"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}" 
  }
}
```

Please help and advise

Comment: please add some actual log samples as well to ensure you get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only filter you are applying in the pipeline, everything that does not match your GROK filter will have a `_grokparsefailure` tag added.
You can use it to drop the events. using below after all the options in your filter are done.

```
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      drop{}
    }
```

So a sample filter can be

```
filter {
    grok {
    match => { message => "Exception" }
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
      drop{}
    }
}
```

Another way to do this can be, add a tag when match happens and then only ingest events that have the tag.
Example

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    tags => "exception"
  }
}
filter{
  if "exception" in [tags]{
    grok {
    match => { message => "Exception"}
    add_tag => [ "exception_match" ]
  }
}
output {
 if"exception_match" in [tags]
  {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
      index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}" 
    }
  }
}
```